# Excel user-defined formula to eliminate special characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a function I use to replace names be for importing data into the payment-system, as this does not accept any Special characters.

```
Function UMLAUT(text As String)
'** Dimensionierung der Variablen
Dim umlaut1, umlaut2, umlaut3, umlaut4, _
umlaut5, umlaut6, umlaut7, umlaut8, umlaut9, _
umlaut10, umlaut11, umlaut12, umlaut13, umlaut14, _
umlaut15, umlaut16, umlaut17, umlaut18, umlaut19, _
umlaut20, umlaut21, umlaut22 As String

umlaut1 = Replace(text, "ü", "ue")
umlaut2 = Replace(umlaut1, "Ü", "Ue")
umlaut3 = Replace(umlaut2, "ä", "ae")
umlaut4 = Replace(umlaut3, "Ä", "Ae")
umlaut5 = Replace(umlaut4, "ö", "oe")
umlaut6 = Replace(umlaut5, "Ö", "Oe")
umlaut7 = Replace(umlaut6, "ß", "ss")
umlaut8 = Replace(umlaut7, "ó", "o")
umlaut9 = Replace(umlaut8, "&", "+")
umlaut10 = Replace(umlaut9, ";", ",")
umlaut11 = Replace(umlaut10, "é", "e")
umlaut12 = Replace(umlaut11, "á", "a")
umlaut13 = Replace(umlaut12, "à", "a")

UMLAUT = umlaut13

End Function
```

this does work fine, but is there a way, where I do not have to look for "new" Special characters every time I Need this. For example the he west data also contains an `è`, which is not exchanged and therefore the import in the banking-software does not work.

Thanks for any help!
Max

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/669780-handling-special-characters-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: Quick question.. How are you deciding then  `"ü"` should be `"ue"`? Similarly for the others...

Comment: @mattboy: thanks for the link, but the StrConv-function does not convert any of the examples in my list of items to be converted, but only "even stranger" Special characters like "Ł"

Comment: @SiddharthRout ü, ä, ö  are in german language often used special characters, that "everybody" would write as ue, ae, oe if he had for example an english keyboard not ofering those Special characters.

Comment: Ok.. Posting an answer.... It's almost ready...

Comment: + 1 Good question :) Had me thinking for sometime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a handy reference to [THIS](http://www.asciitable.com/) ASCII Table

[image]

Also

1. You do not need so many variables.
2. When you declare variables as `Dim umlaut1, umlaut2, umlaut3 As String`, then only the last variable is declared as string in VBA. The first two are declared as `Variants`

Now back to the ASCII table.

If you notice the special chars start from 128 and go up till 255 so simply use a loop to replace the unwanted characters.

**NOTE**: There is a **one time** slogging that you have to do. This will also ensure that you will not have to add more characters in the future. In the code below, simply add the text to be replaced in the same order as shown in the image above.

**Code**: (UNTESTED)

```
Function umlaut(text As String)
    Dim umlaut1 As String, rplString As String
    Dim i As Long, j as Long
    Dim MyArray

    '~~> One time slogging
    rplString = ",ue,e,,a,,,,,,,,......." '<~~ and so on.
    '~~> The first one before the comma is empty since we do
    '~~> not have any replacement for character represented by 128.
    '~~> The next one is for 129 and then 130 and so on so forth.
    '~~> The characters for which you do not have the replacement,
    '~~> leave them empty

    MyArray = Split(rplString, ",")

    umlaut1 = text: j = 0

    For i = 128 To 255
        umlaut1 = Replace(umlaut1, Chr(i), MyArray(j))
        j = j + 1
    Next

    umlaut = umlaut1
End Function
```

**TIP**: If you feel that you could have your solution by only considering up till say, ASCII 166, then simply amend the code accordingly :)

Comment: thanks a lot, that Looks very interesting indeed!

But 2 Problems/questions:
- the code is having #value as result - I do not find the error...
- it seems to me that the ascci-codes are different for different languages - but i look deeper into hat when the code does not provide an error any more...

my rplstring is for the Moment:     rplString = "C,ue,e,a,,a,a,c,e,e,e,i,i,i,,A,e,a,A,o,,o,u,u,,,,o,,O,x,f,a,i,o,u,n,N,a,o,,,,,,i,,,,,,,,A,A,A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,o,D,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,,,,,,I,,O,ss,O,O,o,O,u,b,b,U,U,u,y,Y,,,,,,3/4,,,,,,,,1,3,2," '<~~ and so on.

Comment: did u see my last comment?

Comment: ?chr(128) gives €; 129 = space 130 = „         I thought 128 would be Ç
thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `?Asc("ü")` give you? similarly what does the rest give you? Do you see a pattern? I mean any sequence of numbers?

Comment: ü=252, ä=228, ö=246, ß=223, Ç=199; i get the same results (other wa round) with the formula =CHAR(ROW()) in excel

Comment: so do you see any sequence which you could use in a for loop?

Comment: postet an extra answer as I can not place all the text in a comment with a how-to make the rplstring. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

siddharth's code with additional comments plus

- the rpl_string for german-language;
- for characters eliminated (without replacement) you can put put in any sign you like

.

```
Function umlaut(text As String, Optional replaceEMPTYby As String = "")
    'great thx to Siddharth rout!
Dim umlaut1 As String, rplString As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim MyArray

    '~~> One time slogging
rplString = "EUR,,,f,,,,,,,S,,OE,,Z,,,,,,,,,,,(TM),s,,oe,,z,Y,,i,c,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,A,A,A,A,Ae,A,A,C,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,G,N,O,O,O,O,Oe,x,0,U,U,U,Ue,Y,b,ss,a,a,a,a,ae,a,ae,c,e,e,e,e,i,i,i,i,o,n,o,o,o,o,o,-,o,u,u,u,u,y,b,y" '<~~ and so on.
    '~~> The first one before the comma is empty since we do
    '~~> not have any replacement for character represented by 128.
    '~~> The next one is for 129 and then 130 and so on so forth.
    '~~> The characters for which you do not have the replacement,
    '~~> leave them empty
    'how to find out your own signs: in Excel in Cell A128 type formula =CHAR(ROW())
    'copy that down to 255. replace characters not wanted by the charcater wanted.
    'in B128 formula: =A128
    'in all cells from B129 down to 255 type/copy formula: =CONCATENATE(R[-1]C,"","",RC[-1])
    'paste the value from B255 in "rplstring" above!

If replaceEMPTYby <> "" Then
    rplString = Replace(rplString, ",,", "," & replaceEMPTYby & ",")
    rplString = Replace(rplString, ",,", "," & replaceEMPTYby & ",")
    rplString = Replace(rplString, ",,", "," & replaceEMPTYby & ",")
    If Mid(rplString, 1, 1) = "," Then rplString = replaceEMPTYby & rplString
    If Mid(rplString, Len(rplString), 1) = "," Then rplString = rplString & replaceEMPTYby
    Debug.Print rplString
End If

    MyArray = Split(rplString, ",")
    umlaut1 = text: j = 0

    For i = 128 To 255
        umlaut1 = Replace(umlaut1, Chr(i), MyArray(j))
        j = j + 1
    Next
    umlaut = umlaut1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy tricks because you are using custom substitutions rather than deleting the characters.  You can eliminate the extra String variables:

```
Function UMLAUT(text As String) As String
    UMLAUT = Replace(text, "ü", "ue")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "Ü", "Ue")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "ä", "ae")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "Ä", "Ae")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "ö", "oe")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "Ö", "Oe")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "ß", "ss")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "ó", "o")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "&", "+")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, ";", ",")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "é", "e")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "á", "a")
    UMLAUT = Replace(UMLAUT, "à", "a")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as this?

```
Function replaceSpecialCharacters(givenString As String) As String

    Const SPECIAL_CHARS As String = "áéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝäëõöüÄËIÖÜ"
    Const REPLACE_CHARS As String = "aeiouyAEIOUYaeoouAEIOU"
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(SPECIAL_CHARS)
        givenString = replace(givenString, Mid(SPECIAL_CHARS, i, 1), Mid(REPLACE_CHARS, i, 1))
    Next i

    replaceSpecialCharacters = givenString

End Function
```